# how to get value by key in array of objects javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this object and i want to access the values of the objects by key in ES6 map function

```
ques:[{"q0":"dwdw"},{"q1":"dwdw"},{"q2":"wdwd"},{"q3":"wdwd"},{"q4":"dwwdw"}]
```

Comment: Each object in your array has *different* properties.  That will make it hard to work with.  Try something like `{name: "q0", value: "dwdw"}` or just use an object with "q0", "q1" as property names, or just use a flat array ["dwdw", "dwdw", "wdwd", ...] and reference the elements by index.

Answer (score 3):

You can takes value with [**Object.values**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```
ques.map(e=> Object.values(e)[0] )
```

```js
let ques = [{"q0":"dwdw"},{"q1":"dwdw"},{"q2":"wdwd"},{"q3":"wdwd"},{"q4":"dwwdw"}]

 let op = ques.map(e=> Object.values(e)[0] )
 
 console.log(op)
```